# Why I am getting error "ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE"?

Tags: java

I am using a log4j version 1.2.15, at the time of executing a code I am able to get log file and .html but in console it generate a below error:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.CONSOLE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "CONSOLE".
```

I am using below property file:

```
log4j.rootLogger= INFO,CONSOLE,R,HTML,TTCC

//Here we define the appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TTCC=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HTML=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

// Here we define log file location
log4j.appender.R.File=./log/testlog.log
log4j.appender.TTCC.File=./log/testlog.log
log4j.appender.HTML.File=./log/aplication.html

// Here we define the layout and pattern
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern= [%t:%p] %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern= %d - %c -%p -%m%n

log4j.appender.TTCC.layout=org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout
log4j.appender.TTCC.layout.DateFormat=ISO8601

log4j.appender.HTML.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.Title=Application log
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.LocationInfo= true
```

Also, I don't understand in log file why it print same line twice with "**main**" and "**demo**", please check below:

```
015-08-10 21:25:08,921 - demo -INFO -New driver instantiated
2015-08-10 21:25:08,921 [main] INFO demo - New driver instantiated
2015-08-10 21:25:09,000 - demo -INFO -Implicit wait applied on the driver for 10 seconds
2015-08-10 21:25:09,000 [main] INFO demo - Implicit wait applied on the driver for 10 seconds
2015-08-10 21:25:42,156 - demo -INFO -Web application launched
2015-08-10 21:25:42,156 [main] INFO demo - Web application launched
```

Can anyone please let me know what the exact problem is?
Also, I am trying it first time by seeing the tutorial. So, please help me.

Comment: Have you already tried to use the uppercase "CONSOLE" in the whole config file? (repost to remove an evil typo)

Comment: @Tom Now log is generated in CONSOLE, but in log.file why it generate same line twice link "Main" and "Demo". Please above I've post that file also.

Answer (score 1):

Your root logger definition says `CONSOLE` (all caps). But you are initiating 
`log4j.appender` for `console`(smaller case).

As per log4j [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Loggers_Appenders_and_Layouts)

> Logger names are case-sensitive

Change the line

```
log4j.rootLogger= INFO,CONSOLE,R,HTML,TTCC
```

to

```
log4j.rootLogger= INFO,console,R,HTML,TTCC
```

in order for log4j to initialize properly.